# How to export html table to excel with correct latitude/longitude format?

Tags: javascript, excel, formatting

I have an HTML table that contains 2 columns of latitudes and longitudes. I can easily export this table to excel using the following JavaScript function:

```
function downloadExcel() {
var tab_text = '<html xmlns:x="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel"> <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="application/vnd.ms-excel; charset=UTF-8">';
tab_text = tab_text + '<head><xml><x:ExcelWorkbook><x:ExcelWorksheets><x:ExcelWorksheet>';

tab_text = tab_text + '<x:Name>Results</x:Name>';

tab_text = tab_text + '<x:WorksheetOptions><x:Panes></x:Panes></x:WorksheetOptions></x:ExcelWorksheet>';
tab_text = tab_text + '</x:ExcelWorksheets></x:ExcelWorkbook></xml></head><body>';

tab_text = tab_text + "<table border='1px'>";
tab_text = tab_text + $('#gcResults_table').html();
tab_text = tab_text + '</table></body></html>';

var data_type = 'data:application/vnd.ms-excel; charset=UTF-8;base64,';

var ua = window.navigator.userAgent;
var msie = ua.indexOf("MSIE ");

if (msie > 0 || !!navigator.userAgent.match(/Trident.*rv\:11\./)) {
    if (window.navigator.msSaveBlob) {
        var blob = new Blob([tab_text], {
            type: "application/csv;charset=utf-8;"
        });
        navigator.msSaveBlob(blob, 'Results.xls');
    }
} else {
    $('#test').attr('href', data_type + ', ' + encodeURIComponent(tab_text));
    $('#test').attr('download', 'Results.xls');
}
}// END of downloadExcel()
```

It works perfectly. But when an excel file has exported the table, latitudes and longitudes are not shown in correct format. A sample row of the excel file can be seen below:

[image]

Therefore, my question is, how can I correctly write these coordinates to excel? I have searched allot on several blogs but have not been able to find a solution. Thanks allot for your time and support.

**UPDATE:**
Using the above excel export method, whenever an xls file is exported, I get the following notification when I open the file in MS Excel:

[image]

After clicking on "Yes", it shows me the excel data but format of latitude/longitude is not correct, as it is mentioned above.

Comment: How are the latitudes shown currently and how do you want that to be shown?

Comment: On HTML they look like this "48.210221, 16.390036" and I want them to be exported in this format to excel file. But the format is not retained, as it can be seen in the image above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must specify the data type of the cells as **string** for xml spreadsheet format. Your table should look like:

```
<Table border='1px'>
    <Column ss:Width="75" ss:AutoFitWidth="0"/>
    <Row>
      <Cell>
          <Data ss:Type="String">48.210221, 16.390036</Data>
      </Cell>
    </Row>
</Table>
```

For the mhtml file format a simple table like in the following code, works fine for me:

```
<html xmlns:x="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel"> 
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="application/vnd.ms-excel; charset=UTF-8">
  <head>
    <xml>
      <x:ExcelWorkbook>
     <x:ExcelWorksheets>
            <x:ExcelWorksheet>
        <x:Name>Results</x:Name>
        <x:WorksheetOptions>
            <x:Panes></x:Panes>
        </x:WorksheetOptions>
        </x:ExcelWorksheet>
     </x:ExcelWorksheets>
       </x:ExcelWorkbook>
    </xml>
  </head>
  <body>
     <table border='1px'>
        <tr>
           <td >48.210221, 16.390036</td>
        </tr>

     </table>
  </body>
</html>
```

Be sure that inside the file are indeed those values. Maybe the values are transformed before being saved to the file.

The warning that you get, it's because you are not saving real Excel (xls) file. You have an html file saved with xls extension. MS Excel knows to read HTML files and to display them into a worksheet.

Comment: I tried this as well but it makes no difference to the output excel data. The coordinates are still not in correct format. :(

Comment: Yes, I tried this already. Can you please share your code on jsfiddle?

Comment: I manually created the html file based on your code. When I open the file with MS Excel, the coordinates are ok. This is why I asked you to check if your HTML file is similar with my file. You can open your xls file (html file actually) with Notepad to check.

Comment: @alex.pulver - I think you are on the right track with this. But if you look at OP data it is likely the Excel version has Austrian regional settings with `.` for thousand separator and `,` for decimal separator (opposite to US/ AU settings etc) which is why it works for you and not for @Amir.

Comment: MS Excel always use US settings in file formats and render data using computer regional settings. Inside the file should be "48.210221, 16.390036". If it is something else, then it's a problem.

Comment: Yes your solution works separately but with in my project "index.html", it doesn't. Neverthless, now i solved it using https://github.com/clarketm/TableExport

Answer (score 0):

There is a problem on this because excel (mso-number-format) doesn't support that type of number. I would go and **format it as text** if thats possible in your case.

See this link for avaliable [**mso-number-formats**](http://cosicimiento.blogspot.de/2008/11/styling-excel-cells-with-mso-number.html) and this link for a [**reformatting in excel**](https://www.adventuresincre.com/auto-populate-latitude-longitude-excel/).

Try to add these css classes

```
.text {
   mso-number-format: "\@";
}
.number {
   mso-number-format: General;
}
```

And give these css classes to your data fields.

```
<div class="text">11</div>
<div class="number">11.0</div>
```

Comment: No it doesn't work either. Irrespective of this, if I export the html table to "html" file, then the table is exported with correct format. But I want the data in excel file and in correct format :(

Comment: Also see [Step 4 - number formatting](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/brian_jones/2007/05/29/simple-spreadsheetml-file-part-3-formatting/) - I think its possible, but you have to do a workaround for sure.

Answer (score 0):

Just export from JS as CSV-File and format the coordinates with the syntax ="[NUM]".
Like this:

```
Name;Lat;Lng
Test1;="32.056717";="11.335333"
Test2;="12.056717";="19.335333"
```

In Excel:

[image]

Comment: No, the issue of course doesn't appear when results are written to a CSV file. The format issue happens when I try to write the results to an excel file.